# How to remove a innerHTML li with a class name using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, parent-child, innerhtml, nodelist

I am creating a **Todo App** and I am still new to JavaScript, I have a problem with removing completed tasks with class
(todos)*li.checked* found in the innerHTML from user input.

```
<div class="todo-container">
<ul class="todo-list">
*/<li class="checked">completed task</li>


<li>Uncompleted task</li>*/
</ul>
</div>
<div class="btn" onclick="deletecompletedTask()> deleteAll</div>



JS

const btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
const todoContainer = document.querySelector('.todo-container');
const todolist = document.querySelector('.todo-list);

//Delete completed task
function deletecompletedTask(){
todoContainer.innerhtml = document.getElementByClassName('checked');
todoContainer.removeChild(todoContainer.firstChild);
}
```

Comment: there is no method `getElementByClassName` it's `getElementsByClassName` ... and it returns a collection of elements rather than a single one. Look into `document.querySelectorAll` and its `.forEach` method - also, an element can remove itself from the DOM using its `.remove()` method - and whatever `todoContainer.innerhtml` is, it's wrong

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation**

Hi, I think to achieve what you want, you shall not set the *innerhtml*, but to use the remove function.

Here're some modifications to your script, which it'll first look for all elements with class tagged with *"checked"*. Then, we will use a *"forEach"* loop to remove all of them.

```js
// loop through all the .checked element and remove them 
function deletecompletedTask() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".checked").forEach(function(e) {
    e.remove();
  });
}

// add event listener to delete button
let btn = document.getElementById("deleteBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
    deletecompletedTask();
});
```

```html
<div class="todo-container">
<ul class="todo-list">
<li class="checked">completed task</li>


<li>Uncompleted task</li>
</ul>
</div>

<button id="deleteBtn" class="btn"> deleteAll</button>
```